# How to grep multiple patterns together

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file which has text with some information and has similar structure to the following. 
Note: Please assume ------ as unwanted text. This is other information that I don't care for.

```
==== Start of Info for Employee 1 ====
--------
--------
--------
Start of Address information for employee 1
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
-------
-------
==== Start of Info for Employee 2 ====
--------
--------
--------
Start of Address information for employee 2
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
-------
-------
==== Start of Info for Employee 3 ====
--------
--------
--------
Start of Address information for employee 3
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
-------
-------
```

I am interested in getting the following information by doing a grep or some other way:

```
==== Start of Info for Employee 1 ====
Start of Address information for employee 1
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
==== Start of Info for Employee 2 ====
Start of Address information for employee 2
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
==== Start of Info for Employee 3 ====
Start of Address information for employee 3
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
```

How can I do this?

Comment: is the number of those `----...` lines fixed?  like before the `start of address...` there would be always 3 lines of trash, after `End of Address...` there would be always 2 lines of trash before next block?

Comment: @Kent, yes it is fixed.

Comment: Don't you want suppress the lines with `---...`? In this case, you could do this with grep: `grep -Ev '^-+$'`

Comment: @Bentoy13 my bad, ----- represents text that I don't want or some text. It is not - characters. Just edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @GauravSinha Ok thanks for the update. In that case, I recommend the answer of sputnick :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your text in each block could be dynamic. but you have fixed line numbers, then this works for you:

```
awk '/^====/{print;for(i=1;i<=3;i++)getline;x=0;next}{++x}x<=5' file
```

test with your file:

```
kent$  awk '/^====/{print;for(i=1;i<=3;i++)getline;x=0;next}{++x}x<=5' f
==== Start of Info for Employee 1 ====
Start of Address information for employee 1
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
==== Start of Info for Employee 2 ====
Start of Address information for employee 2
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
==== Start of Info for Employee 3 ====
Start of Address information for employee 3
Street No
City
Zip
End of Address information
```

Comment: Just had to do the count right and I got it working for my actual file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
grep -E '^(==== Start of Info for Employ|Start of Address information|Street No|City Zip|End)' file
```